# Why don't the best/most upvoted answers on this website appear on the top?

Tags: support

I have seen this many times on this website and I am seriously concerned about this issue. I know that self answers are never on top, but in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909280/equivalence-class-testing-vs-boundary-value-testing) the answer which has negative votes is on the top and is also not accepted by the asker. In fact, user did not accept any answer. I think most upvoted answer should be sorted to top of the list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three types of sort ordering for answers. The one you select will be the default when you view the next question.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: Alright!!! But shouldn't it be by default on votes? Its much more helpful I think.

Comment: Changing the tab changes it on all answers.

Comment: @Harshal, added explanation about this behavior.

Comment: @RossRidge Nice. Should I delete this question ? I dont think its a contribution to the community at all maybe.

Comment: @brasofilo .. Aahh Good, thanks :)

Comment: Unless it's already been asked and answered, I think your question is fine.

Comment: [garbage floats on top](http://i.stack.imgur.com/rnzN5.png) -- [business as usual](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/219922/what-is-the-goal-of-hot-network-questions/238443#comment781462_238443 "'When site regular lands in the hot question shown in active mode (btw in regular questions this seems to be much better setting than 'votes'), first thing they see is multiple low quality 'most recent' answers. This is quite frustrating and... makes voting of better answers harder...'") -- it's always like that, [here's a recent example](http://i.stack.imgur.com/jRkkc.png)

Comment: I don't know if the default selection changed, or I selected "active" by accident.  Either way, it was a UX problem for me.  I was confused that answers with 1 vote were at the top, and answers with 200 votes were at the bottom.  By choosing to sort by "votes", I was able to get the desired behavior, which is that the most useful answers appear at the top of the page.  This should be the default, if not already.