# Is the latest answer the most correct answer?

Tags: discussion, voting

I've noticed sometimes that the answer sitting down at the bottom with 0 votes is often the one that answers my question. Because:

- The question is years old and the formerly right answer is out of date.
- The top answer says something interesting or popular or is given by someone popular and no has bothered to scroll down and read the simple truth.

Is there a better way than voting to sort by rightness?

### Update

After a bit of discussion, I'm reminded that Quora has a feature where you can pay (karma) to promote a question or answer. If it's your own question or answer you can see it as a kind of investment where the return is the karma you get from further upvotes. However, if you promote someone else's question or answer then it's just altruistic. (SO bounties are similar but only apply to questions and don't promise a return on investment.) What if we took it one step further and said you can invest karma to promote someone else's question or answer that you think has merit in exchange for a share of the proceeds?

Comment: That's kinda what voting is for. If the lowest scored answer is the one that helped people the most, then it will be voted up so that it is no longer the lowest scored answer.

Comment: I see *lots* of bad answers posted to old questions.  I see it way more often than I see great answers (better than all existing answers) posted to old questions.

Comment: *"Is the latest answer the rightest answer?"* Clearly not always.

Comment: @Servy That's true. I'm often looking at the top and bottom.

Comment: @KevinB Sure. It's just rhetoric.

Comment: The problem is the *most correct* answer may not always be *the best* answer, or the answer that answers the question for everyone that visits. What other ways could we possibly sort answers other than by active, votes, or age? In a perfect world sorting by votes would be sorting by correctness, but that's not what always happens.

Comment: @KevinB That's my question.

Comment: I just don't see any benefit from adding another sorting option. Maybe you should add in an example of what such a sorting option would solve. It seems like to me the questions your targeting primarily are older questions with out of date answers that were highly upvoted where a new answer may be better than the old. However, it may not be better.

Comment: I don't think there is a perfect algorithm to handle this, and it should be kept simple.

Comment: @KevinB What if the answer isn't an algorithm? For example, what if you could challenge an answer and make it incumbent on the original answerer to update or defend his position?

Comment: And, what happens when said answerer doesn't? for example, if the user is no longer active on SO. Obviously the answer wouldn't be removed if it has significant upvotes, but would that really be a signal that another answer would be better at the top?

Comment: @MichaelFox And what forces the user's response to actually be meaningful?  If the user can just click an "this is indeed correct" button, or just post a "I'm right" comment, you've learned nothing.  There's no way to know if the comment they post is correct because that's the exact problem we're trying to solve for the answer.

Comment: @KevinB I don't know. Something to do with karma? It's a game-design question. Hopefully someone knows more than me about that.

Comment: I could see such a challenge instead being a "This post needs to be reviewed by the community" type of thing, but then we have to weigh in the added work that puts on the community in the form of additional moderation.

Comment: @Servy Maybe we have a new game where you pick either an incumbent or a challenger until some threshold causes the challenge to disappear or replace the incumbent?

Comment: @Servy Another idea is wagering. I'll bet 100 karma that if this 0-vote answer gets displayed above this 100-vote answer then it will stay there.

Comment: @MichaelFox You could say that of almost all answer pairs.  Being on top for an extended period of time by an answer that's not complete and utter garbage means that it'll almost certainly stay there.

Comment: see also: [Why don't the best/most upvoted answers on this website appear on the top?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/275531/839601)

Comment: It's interesting to see a forum-like discussion in a question here. Will this discussion affect how Stackoverflow works? Upvote decay + user reputation affecting the upvote are two great solutions suggested here. I think other sorting options can be added to the current 3 options (active/oldest/votes) to help. And for those seeking answers, looking at all answers rather than simply the top ones does make sense.

Comment: If you feel that the accepted/most voted answer is out of date then add a comment below it, and may be link to the current/more appropriate answer. This helps sometimes.

Comment: Note that it's difficult to determine which answer _actually_ helped the most people because many people view answers via a search engine without logging on to the site. And even if they do log on they may not bother to vote.

Answer (score 28):

Is it possible to do better, yes.  Basically, you need to weigh votes based on their age.  Sites like [Reddit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reddit) do this.  The "score" of a post used to determine its ranking is affected not just by the total votes, but when each vote was cast.  A recent vote is "worth more" than an older vote, but older votes are still worth something, they just decay logarithmically.  The exact specifics of such solutions can vary widely, and the intricacies can be quite complex (or simple) depending on what you want the model to do.

Of course there are all sorts of problems with a solution like this, and there are certainly problems inherent in voting in general that this fails to solve.  A solution like this doesn't *guarantee* that you *always* get the best answer first, but it does help address the problem of new answers that are better than much older answers at least having a better shot at competing.

Comment: It's a solution with it's own set of problems. Early answers benefit from inertia and questions posted on Sunday morning EST do better than those posted on Friday night.

Comment: @MichaelFox Early answers benefit from interia *even more* when there is no aging.  The point is that it helps mitigate that inertia, but you are quite right that it doesn't *eliminate* it.  The time that you post it is also relevant, yes.  Note that how relevant it is is dependent on how aggressively votes age.  The "quicker" they age, the less relevant it is.  (Though if SO did apply something like this, it would need to age votes pretty slowly.)

Comment: And if SO did age votes, they would probably want to consider total number of votes on question+answers as well as total visitors (since)... So we have faster aging on more popular posts.

Comment: If we're going to have a rating system where different votes are worth different amounts, why not factor in the voter's rep?  To look at an extreme case, if Jon Skeet upvotes my answer, it's more likely to be correct than if an anonymous user123456 upvotes it.

Comment: @DavidWallace: you mean the voter's rep *in the tags involved* of course? Because while being currently very active in the Rust tag, I am still very much a beginner...

Comment: @MatthieuM. No, I didn't mean any such thing.  I think that could make the algorithm extremely complex.  I think once somebody is reasonably "trusted", their votes could be worth full value, regardless of the tags.  In other words, if somebody is a reasonably high rep user, we trust them not to vote on answers of which they are not qualified to judge the quality and/or usefulness.

Comment: @DavidWallace: Fair enough point indeed!

Comment: [Also relevant.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/49787/137004)  A post with 200 upvotes and 100 downvotes is probably not as good as one with just 100 upvotes, but they have the same score on SO.

Comment: I completely agree with this answer! Based on it and other discussions, I have created a specific feature request here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294637/feature-request-introduce-an-optional-sort-option-for-answers-that-lets-new-go

Answer (score 21):

Unless the voting system is reworked to do something like what @Servy said, there is not a whole ton you can do.  Three things I can think of using the existing system:

- If you are willing to sacrifice some rep, you could open a bounty on the question and give it to the correct answer.  It may not shoot it up to the top, but the blue bounty award next to the answer should call some attention to it.
- People who do what the highly-upvoted answer says yet still have their problem will most likely check the comments on the answer.  So, you can leave a comment  which explains why the answer is wrong and includes a link to the correct answer.

  If there is already a comment that says this, upvote it so that it is more visible.
- Whenever you need to refer to the question, link to the correct answer rather than the most upvoted one.  As you share the link in more places, more people will follow it and see the correct answer.

That said, upvotes are the main way in which this problem is resolved.  You will just have to hope that, over time, the correct answer will float to the top.

Comment: When the best answer is ranked at like 15th, even a bounty can't really draw much attention to it.  It only really helps give weight to an answer that someone else is already taking the time to read (or at least skim).  When the answer isn't even high enough for the user to scroll to it this doesn't do much.

Comment: Comments are good and would be better if at least comments were sorted in reverse order. Otherwise a new comment on a top answer will be buried under "Show more comments".

Comment: @MichaelFox that goes away if the comment gains some upvotes.

Comment: @Servy: The bounty description could be used to call out a specific answer, I believe.

Comment: It seems weird that the points obtained from a bounty wouldn't affect an answer's standing. Isn't rewarding the user supposed to be a *side-effect* of rewarding good answers?

Comment: @Leushenko The primary purpose of the bounty is to give the **question** additional attention, so that it can get a good answer.  It's not designed as much to draw attention to answers.  It *rewards* answers though rep, but it doesn't draw attention to them (at least not compared to *other* answers, it draws attention to *all* answers by just increasing total traffic.)