# Why is the answer with most vote by far ( 52 ) shown as the last answer?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I 've read those two topics ( [Is the latest answer the most correct answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278591/is-the-latest-answer-the-most-correct-answer) and [Why is the accepted answer not on top?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261634/why-is-the-accepted-answer-not-on-top) ).
There is a question with four visible answers, with 0, 2, 3 and 52 upvotes respectively. [adding <script> to wordpress in <head> element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5849057/adding-script-to-wordpress-in-head-element)

I would have expected the exact opposite ordering. Is this a bug?Hope wasn't already asked

Comment: There are three tabs to influence sort order, which one do you have highlighted? With "votes" I see the correct order

Comment: @Pekka웃 i've been using the site for almost 4 years and NEVER saw that. Thanks.

Comment: @Pekka웃 add it as an answer so i can accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three tabs to influence sort order, which one do you have highlighted?

With "votes", I see the correct order.